# jQuery .val() dont work when use `this`

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this `textarea`:

```
<textarea id='ta' onkeydown='down(this)'></textarea>
```

and this JavaSript source:

```
<script>
function down(input) {
    alert(input.val());    // not work
    // but this is work: alert($('#ta').val());
}
</script>
```

why this source not working?

here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7xjqzdu/1/)

Comment: `.val()` is a method of jQuery, so either `$(input).val()` or, better,  native JS `input.value`

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `input` inside a jQuery wrapper using `$()` because `.val()` is a jQuery method.

Try this :-

```
alert($(input).val());
```

OR

```
alert(input.value);  //or use simple javascript '.value'.
```

Answer (score 1):

It s work like this :

```
$(document).on('keyup','#ta',function(){
    alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted? It's entirely legitimate. +1.

Answer (score 0):

The function doesn't get called, and you forgot to add `$()` to `this`

Code:

```
$('#ta').keyup(function() {
   alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7xjqzdu/4/)

Comment: Please leave feedback when voting down, what exactly is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted? It's entirely legitimate. +1.

Comment: Not my downvote, but "the function doesn't get called" isn't true.

Comment: The explanation might be off, but the code should work perfectly fine. Also, I generally advice using `keyup` than `keydown` because the latter is executed before any text input occurs, therefore the value alerted will not reflect the current value of the input.

Comment: @Terry: while this is true, it's unfortunately not explained in the answer. Working code alone doesn't make a good answer.

Comment: @Juhana Normally it would get called, but due to the way jsfiddle works, running this code would end up in giving the error down is not defined, thus it wouldn't get called

Comment: @Paradoxis: It's true that the OP didn't setup the jsFiddle correctly. However, it's not clear that you are referring to the jsFiddle demo. Additionally, since the OP wrote in the code, `// but this is work: alert($('#ta').val());`, we can conclude that that's just a problem with the fiddle and the function is called in their actual code (and that's what we should be focusing on).